# Entity Framework Valdiation Strategies

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I am using database first approach with Entity Framework 6 and generating POCO objects using T4 templates to use them in my WCF service application.

When creating new instances of the POCO objects on the server side if there are any missing required fields, as a final resort if the code missed any, I could call the method GetValidationResult() on the DBContext.Entry to get any validation errors. However I would like to be able to handle any of these on the client end by emitting the Data Annotations on the POCO objects as I am sharing the POCO objects between the Server and Client application.

I was thinking to add buddy classes to define the metadata and create partial classes to configure the buddy class. I was wondering if there are any T4 templates which would help me generate these partial classes with the metadata since there are a lot of entities and also whenever there is an update to the tables the partial classes with the metadata could be updated easily instead of going through each object and updating.

Please let me know whether my thought process is in the right direction and other best approaches.